# Concurret fetch request in Core Data

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

My app is using Alamofire for fetching data in JSON using asynchronous requests to a server. I need to do the following:
 1. Do multiple fetch requests and receive JSON data
 2. Send the JSON data to my `DataImporter` class for importing into Core Data

The DataImporter class has to do the following:
 1. Convert JSON into an array of `NSManagedObject` for storing into Core Data
 2. Fetch the current managed objects from Core Data
 3. Compare the converted objects to the ones that were fetched and update/delete/add new objects
4. Save the state to core data

Here is how I thought I would send the request from my ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url1)
            .responseJSON { response in           
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let value):
                self.dataImporter.importArticles(value)
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url2)
            .responseJSON { response in           
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let value):
                self.dataImporter.importArticles(value)
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Here is how my DataImporter class looks like :

```
class DataImporter {

    private var privateMOC:NSManagedObjectContext!

    init () {
        privateMOC = setupManagedObjectContextWithConcurrencyType(.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    }

    func importArticles(articlesInJson:JSON) {
        self.privateMOC.performBlock { () -> Void in  
        let articles = self.convertJsonToArticle(articlesInJson)
        let fetchedArticles = //return articles using privateMOC
        //compare articles and delete/update/add new articles
        self.privateMOC.save()
    } 
}
```

Now my questions are:
1. Is this an efficient way of importing data from web service?
2. Should I use a different queue for Alamofire request?
3. Is my usage of concurrent MOC correct? Do I need to separate the fetch request and the import into two separate methods?

Comment: Whats the issue? There is nothing wrong with that. Try it and see :D

Comment: I have read a lot of articles and I got everything mixed up in my head. My last attempt on using queues with core data ended up in having unexpected errors and constraint violations. Now I just need someone to confirm that this way is the correct way.

Comment: So the main thing with CoreData and concurrency is that there needs to be a context for that thread/queue. This ties into the issue of not being able to use core data objects across threads, but rather to pass their managedObjectIds across threads so they can be fetched and used. You need to also take care of notifying the UI or other objects about the new data. There is a didSaveNotification where you can access all changes. This is why NSFetchedResultsController is good, it can automatically update the UI when changes occur on the objects its watching with is fetchRequest.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is this an efficient way of importing data from web service?

Yes, as efficient as Alamofire performs these requests concurrently.

However, there's a chance to improve it:

Iff the loaded JSON is large and *bandwidth* is the limiting factor, it may make sense to perform the requests *sequentially*. This has the effect, that the first request finishes faster and the data can be consumed by the second stage - the DataImporter - sooner, and all subsequent requests finish in a more uniformly distributed time. Note, that the import can only process the JSONs sequentially. It can only use *one* CPU - due to the execution context (a serial dispatch queue) of the managed objects.

If you will instead download all datas in parallel, they may arrive all at about the same time, but the Data Importer can only serve *one* data at a time. So, loading them sequentially *may* improve this approach.

> 2. Should I use a different queue for Alamofire request?

You cannot change the underlying worker threads for a network request at all. What you can setup (probably) is the dispatch queue where your delegate will be executed. This queue should not be the main_queue. Choose a global concurrent queue if this is configurable in Alamofire.

> 3. Is my usage of concurrent MOC correct?

As far as I can see, yes. I would however add a completion handler to the method `importArticles` since it is an asynchronous function.

> Do I need to separate the fetch request and the import into two separate methods?

You are calling `importArticles` form within the completion handler of the network request -  this is totally OK. Unless your are utilising a helper class like Promises or Futures, this is the way you have to go.

IMHO, in your case, a solution utilising a library exposing a "Future" or a "Promise" - or any of a "Rx" libraries, may make your code much more comprehensible. It also helps to implement error handling and cancellation in a concise way.